# C# or .NET Implementation of WEKA J48 Class?

Tags: c#, java, .net, algorithm, machine-learning

I am looking for a C# conversion or implementation of the java code of the [J48 Decision Tree class from the WEKA Machine Learning Library.](http://read.pudn.com/downloads122/sourcecode/java/517508/weka-src/weka/classifiers/j48/J48.java__.htm)

While I can convert it myself I am looking to save some time and find a clean commented implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The accord framework has implementations of the ID3 and C4.5 learning algorithms. J48 is the open source version of C4.5.

http://accord.googlecode.com/svn/docs/html/N_Accord_MachineLearning_DecisionTrees_Learning.htm